# How to access class instance variables from a subclass

Tags: ruby

Below is my code with class `MyClass` and class `OtherClass`, which inherits `MyClass`. I have a class variable `@@my_new_var` and a class instance variable `@my_var`.

```
class MyClass
  @@my_new_var = "test"
  @my_var = 1
  def self.read; @my_var end
  def ins_method; @my_var = 2 end
end

class OtherClass < MyClass
  def self.read_another; @@my_new_var end
  def self.test; @my_var end
end
```

We can access class variables from a subclass:

```
OtherClass.read_another # => test
```

but we can't access class instance variables from a subclass:

```
MyClass.read # => 1
MyClass.new.ins_method # => 2
OtherClass.read # => nil
OtherClass.test # => nil
```

Why is that? What is the scope of class instance variables?

Comment: The `@my_var` that appears in `def ins_method; @my_var = 2 end` is not a class instance variable.

Comment: yeah I knew that, class instance variables can be accessed in class methods only if i'm not wrong.

Comment: Class instance variables can be accessed by instances using [Object#instance_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get); e.g., `class Klass; @cat = "meow"; def cat; self.class.instance_variable_get(:@cat); end; end`. Then `Klass.new.cat => "meow"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: Because they are defined so.

Q2: It is the class (which is an instance of the `Class` class).